# Why decode only work in python interpreter?

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, decode

my code :

```
import fcntl, os
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['bash'], bufsize=0, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
p.stdin.write( b'ls -l' + b'\n')
a=str(p.stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
print(a)
```

perfect work in interpreter , but if i use : python3 myscript , i have this error :

```
a=str(p.stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Why ?
Thanks alot

Comment: Hi Thomas Does this question help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: Hello , no my code perfect work in interpreter !